# script to get all long running mysql queries

Tags: linux, shell-script, mysql

I need to get the long running queries on mysql server for alerting purpose. 
Found a way but it doesn't work:

```
show full processlist;
```

It shows **Select sleep(10);** but doesn't show **select * from my_custom_table;**

Comment: `show full processlist` shows connections, but only running queries.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to like the mysql slow query log; see 
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html .   In a nutshell, it can log all queries that take longer than a given threshold for later analysis.

Please be sure to look for the version of the doc that corresponds with your mysql version, as this is a fast moving project these days and newer versions may have features that older versions don't .

Finally, be aware that the slow query log can fill up hard disks very quickly, so you have to keep an eye on things when it's enabled.